# Securing HTTP requests to web services from smartphones

Tags: web-services, security, http, mobile

Can anyone recommend a strong method to secure HTTP requests to a web service from a smartphone client (iPhone, Android, and BlackBerry)? Preferably something more secure than an MD5 hash...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HTTPS (HTTP Secure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure). That's HTTP with SSL encrtpyion.

How to configure that depends on the webserver used. If it's for example Apache HTTP Server, then you should checkout the [SSL/TLS Strong Encryption How-To](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html). Or if it is for example Apache Tomcat, then checkout the [SSL Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

Once done that, just use https:// URLs instead of http:// URLs to access the web service. You can even configure the webserver to redirect from http:// to https:// automatically.

Comment: I am down voting this for the reason that you cannot do that by law, AFAIK, at least for iPhone unless the SSL is for authentication only.